# Несколько вопросов по указателям в С++

Tags: c++, указатели

Возникло несколько вопросов связанных с raw pointers в С++.
Рассмотрим следующий код

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

int main(void) {
    Point* p = new Point;
    delete p;

    /* 
    * Далее выполняется очень большое кол-во разных
    * действий связанных с созданием разных объектов,
    * включая Point, а также их удалением.
    */

    printf("address = %d, x = %f", p, p->x); //строчка X.

    return 0;
}
```

Вопросы:

1. Для очередного создаваемого объекта `Point` выделился как раз тот участок памяти, на который указывает указатель `p`. Возможно ли такое совпадение? Если да - выполнится ли строчка Х успешно?
2. Для очередного создаваемого объекта **НЕ ТИПА POINT** выделился участок памяти, на начало которого как раз указывает указатель `p`. Объект представлен структурой с тремя полями `double`. Возможно ли такое? Если да - выполнится ли строчка Х успешно?
3. Участок памяти выделенный под объект `Point` после его освобождения был передан ОС, а затем стал частью другого процесса. Возможно ли такая ситуация? Если да - чисто теоретически, возможно ли через указатель p обратиться к данным другого процесса?

Comment: На счёт 3 вопроса. Стандарт пока что не оперирует такими понятиями как процесс. Так что передача объектов между процессами является платформозависимыми решениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Так если мне ничего не мешает обратится к полю x структуры такого же
>   типа, расположенной по адресу хранимому в указателе p - как сценарий в
>   строке Х может не выполнится?

Строка Х выполнится, но результат выполнения непредсказуем и может быть ошибочным всегда или иногда. Или даже результат всегда будет не то чтобы правильным, но ожидаемым человеком, который написал этот ошибочный код.

Такой код, какой приведен в вопросе это ошибочный код. Он скомпилируется, но будет работать с ошибкой (возможно, что ошибка будет проявляться иногда, а возможно и никогда, если соответствующий компилятор расположит структуры данных удачным образом). В языке С++ нет защиты от таких ошибок на уровне языка. За это (за отсутствие защиты от таких ошибок) язык С++ многие критикуют. Зато язык С++ позволяет писать более эффективные программы, если программист сам контролирует такие потенциально ошибочные моменты.

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что это не C, а С++.

1,2. После `delete p;` память, на которую указывает `p`, свободна, так что она может быть аллоцирована под что угодно (если позволяет объем соответствующего непрерывного куска свободной памяти). Так что описанное вами вполне возможно. О строке `x` см. далее.

3. Нет, это адресное пространство, выделенное процессу. Вы просто получите, обращаясь по указателю, память по которому освобождена, undefined behaviour.

Строчка `x` полукорректна :) - адрес вы можете вывести в любом случае - *просто как содержимое переменной* `p`, что еще не означает его корректности, что к нему можно обращаться. Обращение `p->x` работает только в том случае, если вы обращаетесь к корректно выделенной и не освобожденной памяти (или к адресу переменной - типа

```
Point pp;
p = &pp;
```

). После `delete p;` это становится UB (понятно, что после `p = &pp;` само освобождение `delete p;` является UB).

Если между удалением и выводом у вас вновь выполнено присвоение `p` указателя на выделенную память или адреса объекта `Point` - то строка `x` корректна.

Вкратце так. Можно расписывать и более подробно, но...

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю - указатель это просто число, которое интерпритируется как адрес в памяти. Предположим сценарий №1 описанный мной - выполнился. Что (на уровне реализации языка) помешает мне обратиться через указатель p к полю x нового объекта Point?

Comment: Ничего не помешает. Более того, вам ничего не помешает, даже если сценарий не выполнится :)

Comment: извините, опять не совсем вас понял. Так если мне ничего не мешает обратится к полю x структуры такого же типа, расположенной по адресу хранимому в указателе p - как сценарий в строке Х может не выполнится?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что вы можете это написать, это скомпилируется.  Может даже выполниться с ожидаемым результатом (если у вас действительно новая структура будет по тому же адресу), но может и дать какой-то другой результат - если при другом запуске программы адрес будет другим. Если там будет другая структура (п. 2) - то, например, при том же адресе из-за выравнивания может быть что-то иное. Словом, язык не запрещает так делать, но о результате не говорит ничего - на то и UB...

Comment: @Bakuard. Указатель это только адрес в памяти.  p->x это указатель в памяти + смещение, вычесленное для этой структуры на этапе компиляции, + разыменование. Что там окажется, хрен знает. Вы даже можете написать p = random(); std::cout << p->x; И если диапазон (&(p->x), &(p-x)+sizeof(x)) лежит на одной странице доступной вам странице памяти, он отработает.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко Спасибо, ваш комментарий окончательно внес ясность в мой вопрос.

Comment: "адрес вы можете вывести в любом случае" - это не совсем верно. После того как время жизни объекта, на который указывал указатель `p` подошло к концу, в указателе `p` хранится invalid pointer value. Доступ к значению такого указателя - это поведение, определяемое реализацией. В частности, в стандарте явно оговорено, что это может привести к аварийному завершению работы программы. [basic.stc 4.](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4)